# How to create a file dialog that returns file paths for both selected files AND directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I'm trying to use `QFileDialog` to get a list of the paths of selected folders **AND** directories.

I know how to do one or the other using `QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames` and `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory`, but not both at the same time.

The C++ docs and other questions elsewhere didn't seem to help me no matter how much I googled.

I am using `PyQt5 5.14.2` and `Python 3.8.2` on Windows.

Edit:
I've managed to conjure up the following solution not using the native Windows dialog and it works but seems 'hacky'. Can anyone think of a better solution?

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


main_window = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

dlg = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()
dlg.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Directory)
dlg.setOption(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog, True)

_list = dlg.findChild(QtWidgets.QListView, 'listView')
if _list:
    _list.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)

tree = dlg.findChild(QtWidgets.QTreeView, 'treeView')
if tree:
    tree.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)

selected = None

if dlg.exec():
    selected = dlg.selectedFiles()

print(selected)
```

Comment: do you want to be able to select files and directories? Or do you want to get the directories of the selected files?

Comment: I want to be able to select files and directories. What I am trying to do is create a zip archive from selected files and folders using their file paths (it's more complex than this but you get the gist).Actually, that's a thought, it would be sufficient enough to select files and get the child files in a selected folder/directory - not what I would like but I could work with it.

Comment: The solution proposed in the edit is probably the only possible, as QFileDialog only allows to select either files *or* directories, not both.

Comment: I'm going to keep digging later tomorrow as the current solution seems dodgy, most of the time you can't highlight files first as then the select button gets greyed out, you have to highlight a folder then files (so doesn't work at all if you just want to select files).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug opened several years ago](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-720) asking for this feature. Feel free to vote for it to get the attention of Qt developers