# PyQt QFileDialog - select file or directory with the same dialog?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

Is it possible to select either file or directory with the same type of file dialog, using native OS capabilities? Preview on MacOS, for example, can open every valid document in a directory, if only the directory is chosen.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

selected = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(None, "select something")
print(selected)
quit()
```

Comment: I'm not sure about what you exactly mean with "native OS capabilities", but start by reading a similar question posted some hours ago: [How to create a file dialog that returns file paths for both selected files AND directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345234/)

Comment: Convenient! It seems like they also couldn't figure out a way to do it with the native dialog, unfortunately.

Comment: Since the native dialog is provided by the system, there's very limited control on its behavior, and you can't really do that much about it: you either use what the Operating System provides (with its pros and cons), or you use your own implementation (with *other* pros and cons ;-) ).